# Emacs on MacOS 12.5+: Commands failed with 127

Tags: debugging, osx, mac

I recently started working at a company that mandates we all use MacOS. I have installed emacs and would like to use my config, which leverages `visual-regexp-steroids.el`, but I am receiving an OS error that some executable is not found. I am not sure how to debug this.

My normal toolkit of `debug-on-error` and the like is not working.

At first, I thought the issue was related to the path of whatever binary is being invoked, but I can't confirm that. Any help here would be appreciated.

This config works perfectly fine on my personal linux machine, so I assume there's some configuration quirk I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: Bisect your init file, to find the culprit? Where/how are you getting the "127" error? Is that an Emacs error (I'm guessing no)?

Comment: 127 is an OS error. I do not know how to discover the function invoked prior to the 127, and reading through the package code doesn't reveal anything obvious to me. I can try and bisect init, although I was hoping this was somewhat of a known problem since this init is just my normal init applied to a macOS emacs build. ty~~

Comment: does your config work fine if `visual-regexp-steroids` is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

`visual-regexp-steroids` relies on a Python helper. By default, it calls this helper with the `python` executable ([as seen here](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/blob/a6420b25ec0fbba43bf57875827092e1196d8a9e/visual-regexp-steroids.el#L49)) which no longer exists on macOS. There's a myriad of ways to address that, but if it was me, I'd just change that locally to `python3`, and the Homebrew `python3` at that.

It's been a bit since `visual-regexp-steroids` has seen an update, but it wouldn't hurt to [submit a new issue](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/issues).